# JQuery move all select options TEXT to another select

Tags: jquery, select, appendto

How can i move all of the options TEXT from one select to another select? Is there a way to use collect everything in the first select then append each options text to the other select?

first select:

```
<select class="multiple" name="selectMajors" id="selectMajors" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="description">description id</option>
   <option value="description">description id</option>
   <option value="description">description id</option>
</select>
```

second select:

```
<select class="multiple" name="selectedMajors" id="selectedMajors" multiple="multiple">
</select>
```

So I want to move the text (description id) not the values of the 3 options in selectMajors into selectedMajors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure with something like this:

```
    $('#selectedMajors').append(
        $('#selectMajors').html()
    ).find('option').removeAttr('value');
```

See [this working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly0hw9br/1/)

**note**: per your request, this simply copies all options from one to the other, without the value attribute. It does not pay any attention to what is selected. I realize this may not be quite what you had in mind.

HTH,
-Ted

Comment: Using this without the .find. Doing an empty() on the one I don't need the options in anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you expected.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#copy").on("click", function() {
    var copiedOptions = $("#toBeCopied option").removeAttr('value').clone();
    $("#copied").html(copiedOptions);
  })


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="toBeCopied" id="toBeCopied">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select name="copied" id="copied"></select>
<button id="copy">copy</button>
```